# Batch or Banner to indicate the new updates - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please suggests me how to create a batch/button like this and once you click it tableview scrolls to top. I don't know what this kind of controller is called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party tool to create button like this.

[BFPaperButton](https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperButton)

On button click event use `scrollsToTop` attribute of your `UITableView` to scroll tableview at the top.